# How should I define an empty slice in Go?

Tags: go

Or more precisely, it seems like I could do any of these three things. Is there any difference between them? Which is the best and why?

1. `var foo []int`
2. `foo := []int{}`
3. `foo := make([]int, 0)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference is:

(1) The variable is initialized to the zero value for a slice, which is nil (`foo == nil`).

(2) and (3) assign non-nil slices to the variable (`foo != nil`). The slice's underlying array pointer is set to an address reserved for 0-byte allocations.

The following points are true for all three statements:

- The slice length is zero: `len(foo) == 0`.
- The slice capacity is zero: `cap(foo) == 0`.
- The statement does not allocate memory.

[Playground example](https://go.dev/play/p/h95d4j9uhEl)

Because [len](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#len), [cap](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#cap) and [append](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#append) work with nil slices, (1) can often be used interchangeably with (2) and (3).

Statements 2 and 3 are [short variable declarations](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations).  These statements can also be written as a variable declaration with an initializer.

2. `var foo = []int{}`
3. `var foo = make([]int, 0)`

All of the options are used commonly in Go code.

Comment: Are you sure that 2 and 3 don't allocate? This shows otherwise (checking RES on top): http://play.golang.org/p/105KU6MsD3  it uses 244 MB but if you comment out the for loop, it is 15 MB. EDIT: nevermind. runtime.MemStats shows the allocation at make([][]int) but no more allocations in the loop, I suppose it is not accessed so it is not actually allocated but simply reserved.