# What's the difference between make([]int, 0), []int{}, and *new([]int)?

Tags: go, slice

According to https://play.golang.org/p/7RPExbwOEU they all print the same and have the same length and capacity. Is there a difference between the three ways to initialize a slice? Is there a preferred way? I find myself using both `make([]int, 0)` and `[]int{}` with the same frequency.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28052933/how-should-i-define-an-empty-slice-in-go/28053182

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This initializes a 0 length slice.

```
make([]int, 0)
```

Using `make` is the only way to initialize a slice with a specific capacity different than the length. This allocates a slice with 0 length, but a capacity of 1024.

```
make([]int, 0, 1024)
```

This is a slice literal, which also initializes a 0 length slice. Using this or `make([]int, 0)` is solely preference.

```
[]int{}
```

This initializes a *pointer* to a slice, which is immediately dereferenced. The slice itself has not been initialized and will still be nil, so this essentially does nothing, and is equivalent to `[]int(nil)`

```
*new([]int)
```

Comment: The last bit isn't right. Per the spec: "The built-in function new takes a type T, allocates storage for a variable of that type at run time, and returns a value of type *T pointing to it. The variable is initialized as described in the section on initial values." So *new([]int) should be equivalent to []int{}.

Comment: @Adrian: `new` can't initialize a slice. The zero value for a slice is nil, so you get an initialized pointer to a nil slice. https://play.golang.org/p/lVL9Tkxk_D